# A Rails Debugger from Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I have used a Rails debugger before,which I can debug Rails  applications in chrome,just like debugging javascript,I can set breakpoint.

But I forgot now,who can tell me what is the debugger,thanks!

Comment: Have you googled `rail debugger chrome` ? https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel and read the 5th off-topic question http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were looking for Rails Panel.
here the link [Rails Panel Google Chrome pluging](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/railspanel/gjpfobpafnhjhbajcjgccbbdofdckggg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read [official guide on Rails debugger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html), [Chrome DevTools extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) and [post on several approaches to Rails-app debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/sample-extensions#rails_panel)

Comment: Links should have descriptive names. "this" is a terrible, terrible name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but not these.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to debugger on chrome browser.
you have to use rails console to debug the code and install the gem 'debugger'
and where you want to debug the code write the 'debugger' For ex

`class Jai < ApplicationController

def show

# for stop the for debugging

debugger

end

end
`

for more information please visit
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: but I really meet a tool to debugger on  chrome browser,maybe I can debugger on all browsers,just like debug javascript.

Comment: We can debug the javascript but we can not do that for rails in client side in any browser. because it is server side scripting language.

Comment: That is just open a debug server to debug Rails like debug js